# Subbing multiple values into an equation from a dataframe to return results

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

So I get a number of preformatted equations (from a colleague whose code I'm not privy to) that look like this: 3.0 x^{3} - 0.05 - 0.5 y^{2} + 0.01 y - 0.07

Essentially I'd like to sub in the values from the dataframe below to get a list of outputs

I can't manage to format the equation in a way that'll allow me to sub in the values for x and y.

I've tried the Eq() function on the equation but it doesn't like the string. 
Subs() doesn't like string which lead me to have a go at using the Sympy parser which pops up more errors leading me down a rabbit hole.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    x   y
0   58  5

z = '3.0 x^{3} - 0.05 - 0.5 y^{2} + 0.01 y - 0.07'

z.subs({x:58, y: 5})



AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Comment: use str.replace()

Answer (score 0):

Here it would be good to know if the syntaxe is always the same. If so, I would advise you to create little functions using replace.

The code below works for this exemple but might not if you have really different syntaxes sometimes.

```py
In [1]:
z = '3.0 x^{3} - 0.05 - 0.5 y^{2} + 0.01 y - 0.07'

## My functions

def power(string):
    string = string.replace("}", "")
    string = string.replace("^{", "**")
    return string
def minus_and_plus(string):
    string = string.replace(" - ", "-")
    string = string.replace(" + ", "+")
    return string
def time(string):
    string = string.replace(" ", "*")
    return string

## Make sure to use `minus_and_Plus` before `time()`. Otherwise you would have * where you do not want
z = power(z)
z = minus_and_plus(z)
z = time(z)
x=2
y=0

## `eval()` works like subs() but works with strings
eval(z)
```

The output is

```py
Out [1]:
23.88
```

Comment: Thank you for that very helpful - I agree I can't predict the syntax and may ask them to use something a bit more friendly for computing.